# MC Connect - Select Email address from a connected DE in "data designer"

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect

we are having a MC Connector integration between SFCRM and SFMC . Currently the Journey settings ]doesnt allow to use any other data extension connected in the Conatct Builder to be used as source for Email address.It shows only synchronized DE .

We ensure the other DE  with email address is already connected to Journey Entry De in Contact Builder.  Why is the other DE not appearing in Contact Builder ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Data Extensions that are connected as Populations will be listed in this drop down. You should only have 3 populations in the account. Populations

I would suggest putting the email address in the entry source DE and then use the option above this to select your email address as needed